# Email address inside <>tag is taken as html tag and unable to display in UI? How to fix this?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, tags, jakarta-mail

I want to display the email address inside '<test@gmail.com'>' tag in UI, how can I achieve this? How to display email address with tag in UI?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <br> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
    <br> be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
    <br> <test@gmail.com>: host mx.gmail.com[136.143.191.44] said: 550 5.1.1
    <br>     <test@gmail.com> User unknown (in reply to RCPT TO command)
    <br> Reporting-MTA: dns; smtp5.to.test.com
    <br> X-Postfix-Queue-ID: E982A3346F
    <br> X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; test1@test.in
    <br> Arrival-Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 17:37:11 +0530 (IST)
    <br> Final-Recipient: rfc822; test@gmail.com
    <br> Original-Recipient: rfc822;test@gmail.com
    <br> Remote-MTA: dns; mx.zoho.com
    <br> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 <test@gmail.com> User unknown
</body>
</html>
```

**It is display as in below image, not displaying email address with tag**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some characters are reserved in HTML.
If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.
Character entities are used to display reserved characters in HTML.
A character entity looks like this:
&entity_name;
OR
&#entity_number;

To display a less than sign (<) we must write: &lt or &#60

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below is how you'd update the test@gmail.com to some other variable. Simply use javascript to change emailHolderVariable to whatever email address you want it to be. The "&#60" and "&#62" tags (with a semi-colon on the end) mean "<" and ">" when the file is read. For a full list of these codes, please visit https://www.teachucomp.com/special-characters-in-html-tutorial. I hope this answer helps you out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<p id="content-holder">random placeholder</p>
<script>
    var emailHolderVariable = "test@gmail.com"
    var emailInput = "&#60;" + emailHolderVariable + "&#62; Your text here...";
    var contentHolder = document.getElementById('content-holder');
    contentHolder.innerHTML = emailInput;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to use this in java, can I check if @ contains inside tag then don't take that as tag

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to load the variable from java into javascript (other than by reading from a file) but once the variable is in the html/js file, then you could use 
 if (var.includes("@")) {do stuff} on it.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you have to escape some special characters in your text. If you are using a templating engine like Velocity there are usually build-in mechanism for proper escaping (in case of Velocity the [EscapeTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html).

If you use simple string concatenation you should use [Apache Commons Text's StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4​()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) method or equivalent **for all** your text content but not for the tags.

Something like:

```
String htmlFragment = "<p>" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4​(plainText) + "</p";
```

Answer (score 1):

declare this variable

```
  adress:string ='<test@gmai.com>'
```

then bind it on your html file :

```
<br> {{adress}}
```

it works for me